# Uploading files to IPFS using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, ipfs, nft

I am trying to upload files from my computer onto IPFS. I have made two folders with their own CID. I have all my information on the Status page: Peer ID, UI, Gateway, API, Addresses, and a Public key. I have Python code to upload to this one website, that went like

```
def upload_file_to_ipfs()
   idx = 1
   while idx != LIMIT:
      file_path = PATH/TO/FILE.ext
      file = open(file_path, "rb)
   
      response = request.post(
      "https://api.website.xyz/v0/files",
      headers = {"Authorization": "<key>"},
      files = {"file": file}
      )
```

what would go inside the response when it comes to uploading to IPFS? I have very limited experience when it comes to using API calls. Has anyone done this before?

I tried uploading one image with drag and drop and seeing the path of that, and I tried uploading it with the call above with different paths. I could not see the resulting image I want when I tried to open it on the web.

Comment: There's nothing specifically IPFS related that I see in this post, you seem to be using HTTP with a service you didn't specify.